# Performance between Object and Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to architect my NoSQL database scheme.

I have 2 options.

The first option is `Object`.

```
teachers: {
  key: { name, age, subject, email },
  key: { name, age, subject, email },
  ...
}
```

And the second option is `Array`.

```
teachers: [
  { name, age, subject, email },
  { name, age, subject, email },
  ...
]
```

If I use the `Object`, I can `take`, `update` and `remove` the item easily.

But when I display them, I have to convert them to `Array` using `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()`.

Otherwise, If I use the `Array`, I have to traversal all item when I `take`, `update` and `remove` one item. and it may cost `O(n)`.

But I don't need to convert them for displaying.

so, I wonder which structure is better choice for my situation and why.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of getting keys and then iterating over them use `for..in` loop.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between `key` and an integer index?

Comment: @Tibrogargan `key` is just an `Unique Key`. and index is also practically the same.

Comment: Yes, obviously.  What is the difference *in your architecture*?  You've replaced an Object that implements a collection that only allows integer keys with an Object that implements a collection that uses an arbitrary key types.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I would like to display them on the web page and manage them like removing, updating.

Comment: @Tibrogargan when I try to remove one of them, If they are `Array`, I have to traversal them. But, If they are `Object` I don't need to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has a high potential to be completely opinion based.

Comment: You will need to provide an example.  There is no apparent semantic difference between `var idx = 0; var teacher = teachers[idx];` and `var idx = 'arbitraryValue'; var teacher = teachers[idx];`

Comment: @Tibrogargan but, As far as I know, `for-in` or `Object.keys()` are slower than `Array loop` even though it slower only a few microseconds.

Comment: @Chipster Thank you and I expected that, but I just wanted to know the Universal architecture in NoSQL

Comment: I'm wondering if Donald Knuth's famous quote is apropos

Comment: @Tibrogargan  May I ask you what is it?

Comment: "“The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.”.  You probably want to read the documentation for the NoSQL engine you're planning on using and follow their recommendations.